# Anonymizing Google Pagespeed

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I'm new to javascript. How do I anonymize Google Pagespeed?

Here is the original code:
http://pastebin.com/xRbTekDA. It works when I load the page

Here is the anonymize code: http://pastebin.com/fj9rP7FM. It shows a javascript error every time I load the page. It says "ReferenceError: runPagespeedCallbacks is not defined" because I anonymized it.

How do I anonymize that original code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is the method the code is expecting to call is not in scope.  So if you modify the code slightly this should rid you of the error.  This code should fix the issue. http://pastebin.com/RrQ2848j

Notice i'm just returning the callback function and assigning it as a variable. There are other approachs you can take but there needs to be something in the global scope to call.

The reason for this is a script block is being created to get script and data, because an AJAX(XHR) request would violate the same-origin policy trying to reach out to google.com while executing on yourdomain.com .  When the script is downloaded, it's going to expect to call a function in the global scope to pass some data into it. That function is named on the query string of the SRC attribute when creating the script block as shown here:

```
function runPagespeed() {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.async = true;
  var query = [
    'url=' + YN_URL,
    'callback=runPagespeedCallbacks',
    'key=' + API_KEY
  ].join('&');
  s.src = API_URL + query;
  document.head.insertBefore(s, null);
}
```

Comment: Do you understand why? I feel like since you're a student it's my responsibility to make sure you know why now. :-)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. You returned the runPagespeedCallbacks() function and assigned it to the runPagespeedCallbacks variable (like you said), so the callback function would work

Comment: You aren't wrong. Feel free to pm me if you have any questions.

Comment: Will do. Thank you again. I really appreciate the help and explanation

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the two is that the second is wrapped in an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE). The IIFE encapsulates the code so that the free variables are not globally visible. Normally this is a good thing, but if other services rely on that code, it will not be visible.

Comment: I want to hide it from the global scope. It's my assignment for my internship. My supervisor wants me to anonymize it so people can't change the API_KEY and call the functions from console

Comment: Ok so what you're trying to accomplish is to only expose certain parts of the code to global while hiding others.

Comment: Well, as you said, this is your assignment. We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: The runPagespeedCallbacks function needs to be in global scope either as a function, or a function of someother object that is in global scope, and you would need to adjust the callback parameter accordingly in the runPagespeed method.

Comment: @RickViscomi, you're such a good citizen.  I'm here with the intent on answer some SO questions though. If you opt to cheat, at least make sure you take away some learnings from it. :-)

Comment: @RickViscomi, don't you think I tried figuring it out myself? I spent almost half of my work day yesterday, and 2 hours of work day today trying to figure it out. I don't want to waste my time trying to read about anonymous functions when I don't even understand most of it. That's why I tried getting help here because I read about 5-10 tutorials/articles about anonymous functions and most of them were not real world examples.

Comment: I'm relatively new to SO. I'm just trying to fit in with the homework Nazis we have here. Sorry, I thought it was against the rules or something to answer blatant homework questions.